# How to show DialogBox when Mouse colliding a Color

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I have a problem about collision detection in maze programming. In that maze user must drawing way path with mouse movements from start point to end point. 
Output program : [Here](http://s29.postimg.org/d30ul4dav/Untitled.png)

In that program user must draw from start (left) to end (right). The problem is how to show DialogBox when user colliding wall in that maze.
 
Here the syntax :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DummyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool startPaint = false;
        int? initX = null;
        int? initY = null;
        Graphics g;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Maze.png");
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            startPaint = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (startPaint)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, float.Parse("4"));
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(initX ?? e.X, initY ?? e.Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                initX = e.X;
                initY = e.Y;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            startPaint = false;
            initX = null;
            initY = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81315/detect-mouse-collision-over-an-object) has your answer ?

Comment: How do you attempt to detect such a collision? Have your searched web for 'show DialogBox'??

Comment: Sorry, i've mistake i mean MessageBox not DialogBox.